# AS2 tell clip to goto frame from within it's parent clip's function

Tags: function, flash, parent-child, actionscript-2

This one is puzzling, I have a movie clip with the instance name "dog" that sits inside the timeline of another clip on the main stage.

Dog has two labeled frames, "sit" and "bark".

I set an interval to tell this.dog to gotoAndPlay a specific frame label "bark" every 500ms.

```
barkInt=setInterval(bark, 500);

function bark():Void {
this.dog.gotoAndPlay("bark");
    }
```

If i tell dog to bark directly from that clips' s timeline it works-

```
this.dog.gotoAndPlay("bark");
```

But it does not work from within a function.   Any ideas why that would be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you must reference movie clip "dog" by it's instance name, since it is nested somewhere.

Learn from the best! http://fileforever.net/0qadm2kevm57.html (it's saved in CS5)

Comment: Sorry, i didn't mention that the clip named dog is also named with the instance name "dog".  am I not referencing it correctly?

Comment: clip In the library can be named as you like, Instance name is what matters, in case clip is instantiated(placed on stage by hand or code), -- 'AS linkage' is another property you can name as you like, and it will be used to instantiate(create an instance) of an item through code. Thus after ull, need to provide instance name for it also by code.

Comment: ogh, to be more precise = in this context, a movie clip holds an instance of another movie clip. Movie clips actually are never nested.

Answer (score 0):

Found a work around.

By setting a temporary variable that references it from the root path-

```
_root.myVar="dog";

Object(_root).[_root.myVar].gotoAndPlay("bark");

Pretty clunky but it works.  thanks all. :)
```